# Thread Calculation OCaml

Tags: multithreading, ocaml

I tried to create a thread which does a calculation of the fibonacci-numbers. That worked fine, but then I tried to create another thread that stops the calculation-thread if it takes more than x seconds to calculate.

Here is my code:

```
 module TimedFuture : sig
   type 'a t
   val create : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> float -> 'b t
   val get : 'a t -> 'a option
 end = struct

 type 'a t = 'a Event.channel

 let create f a t =
 let c = Event.new_channel () in
 let rec loop f = f (); loop f in
 let task () =
   let b = f a in
   loop (fun () -> Event.(sync (send c b)))
 in
 let start_calc_thread () =
   let t1 = Thread.create task () in
   while ((Unix.gettimeofday () -. t) < 1.0) do
     Printf.printf "Thread should keep running: %f\n"
                  (Unix.gettimeofday () -. t);
   done;
   try Thread.kill t1 with t1 -> ();
   Printf.printf "Thread stoped\n"
 in
 let _ = Thread.create start_calc_thread () in
 c

let get c = Some Event.(sync (receive c))
end


let option_to_i o = match o with
              | None -> 0
              | Some x -> x

let test =
let rec f x = match x with
            | 1 -> 1
            | 2 -> 1
            | _ -> f (x-1) + f (x-2)
in
let t = Unix.gettimeofday () in
let ff = TimedFuture.create f 40 t in
Printf.printf "\nResult: %i\n" (option_to_i (TimedFuture.get ff)),
ff
```

When I compile the code and run it, the calculation thread doesn't stop working, although I get the "Thread stopped" in terminal.

Do you see my fault?

Comment: You are ignoring the errors from Thread.kill, as `try Thread.kill t1 with t1 -> ();` It would be interesting to look in the error – BTW Why call the exception t1? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001959/interrupt-a-call-in-ocaml

Answer (score 0):

A thread can be interrupted in only specific cancellation points, in particular, in points where a user code passes control back to the runtime, so that the latter can do its work. One particular cancellation point is allocation. Since your code doesn't allocate, and reasonably implemented Fibonacci will not allocate either, it is not possible to stop it. If your real algorithm indeed doesn't have cancellation points, then you should either add them explicitly or use processes. To add explicit cancellation point, one can just add `Thread.yield`.